# Getting the values of an unnamed column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Based on a pandas object returned by a market data API, the following snippet

```
index_history['close'].head()
```

prints out

```
symbol            time      
SPY R735QTJ8XC9X  2008-11-25    69.068197
                  2008-11-26    69.970783
                  2008-11-27    72.402075
                  2008-11-29    73.101376
```

How can I retrieve the third column containing the actual closing prices as a list?

Comment: Is this a dataframe or a series? Kinda looks like a series with multiindex..

Comment: Probably a series, based on an error message I get later in my code.

Comment: cant you just do `list(index_history['close'])`? This looses the index of course. I mean if it is a series. `symbol` and `time` is just a part of the index, and `'close'` would be the name of your column.

Comment: Yes I can! if you promote it to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
list(index_history['close'])
```

This looses the index of course. It is a series so `symbol` and `time` is just a part of the index, and `'close'` would be the name of your column.